# Unattended install for Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, usb-installation

I'll revisit the question here - [Lubuntu 18.04: Unattended install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208822/lubuntu-18-04-unattended-install) - asked a few years ago but never answered. Is is possible to have an unattended install of Lubuntu? Cloud-init is only for Ubuntu server, but should something like kickstart or preseeding work with Lubuntu? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like recent versions (18.10 and newer) of Lubuntu use *calamares* as the installer.  Based on [this submitted issue](https://github.com/calamares/calamares/issues/508) there is currently no automated install option for *calamares*.

> right now is that there's literally nothing for automated installations.

It looks like Lubuntu used *ubiquity* [before the 18.10 release](https://lubuntu.me/cosmic-released/#more-3236).  Automation is possible in ubiquity using [preseed files](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation).  I would assume that these older releases of Lubuntu would also support this method, but I have not tried it.

Another option is to install Ubuntu and convert it to Lubuntu.  Then you can use the automated installation methods supported by Ubuntu.  The basic approach to convert is to simply install `lubuntu-desktop`.

See Also

- [How to switch from Ubuntu 18.04 to Lubuntu while keeping the home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212252/how-to-switch-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-lubuntu-while-keeping-the-home-directory)
- [How do I change from Ubuntu 18.04 to Lubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094612/how-do-i-change-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-lubuntu-18-04)
- [How to change Ubuntu into Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18248/how-to-change-ubuntu-into-lubuntu)